# jekyll not respecting _config.yml -- possible to upgrade?

Tags: ppa, ruby, jekyll

Ubuntu 14.04 | default ruby 1.9.1 | Jekyll 0.11.2

Jekyll isn't respecting a number of my settings in _config.yml. I'm guessing this is because current Jekyll (gem) version is 2.3.0, but I could be wrong.

The specific settings being ignored are:

- pagination
- destination

Both of these problems mess with the urls created by Jekyll. Is there a way to either:

- Safely update Jekyll to the current version (not break Ubuntu)?
- Force Jekyll to recognize my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, some applications in Debian/Ubuntu tend to be very old, with Ruby we generally prefer to avoid system packages. There are some very robust Ruby managers like [RVM](http://rvm.io/) (recommended for beginners) and [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) which create an isolated Ruby installation in your home directory, so you have everything up-to-date and under control.

However, if you only wish to use Jekyll, packaged version of Ruby will work for you too, you can just install the latest version of Jekyll through [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/) with a complementary `gem` command (part of the `ruby` package).

First you will need development files for Ruby (`ruby-dev` package) as some Jekyll's dependencies require compilation. Additionally, the latest Jekyll version requires some JavaScript interpreter (e.g. `nodejs`):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev nodejs
```

Now you have two options. You can install Jekyll globally or locally in your home directory.

**The global installation** is easier since you don't need to configure pretty much anything. Just uninstall the `jekyll` package and install the `jekyll` gem with sudo:

```
sudo apt-get remove jekyll
sudo gem install jekyll
```

This will install Ruby dependencies into `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1` and `jekyll` executable into `/usr/local/bin/jekyll`. Then just verify the version of Jekyll by running:

```
jekyll --version
```

Global installation may seem scary, but it won't cause any problems, especially if you just need Jekyll and don't do any heavy Ruby development.

**The local installation** in your home directory can be done in a few ways, here I will place `jekyll` executable into `~/bin` directory – which should be automatically added into your `$PATH`.

```
gem install --user-install --bindir ~/bin jekyll
```

With `--user-install` option, gems will be installed into `~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1`/

`--bindir` tells where the executable should go. If `~/bin` doesn't exist yet, gem may complain:

```
WARNING:  You don't have /home/<user>/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
```

You may just need to reload your terminal or logout.

You can also add these options to the `.gemrc` file, so they are always used when running `gem`:

```
gem: --user-install --bindir ~/bin
```

Note that if you want to use additional plugins for Jekyll and/or wish to use Jekyll for GitHub pages, you should also consider using Bundler to manage your dependencies, as described in [this GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages).

Comment: should be `jekyll --version`. Thanks!!